# bash ./s300928290.sh permission denied

Tags: ubuntu

[image]
      what is the problem? I want to know why

Comment: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text

Answer (score 2):

Only root has execute permissions on the script, and your current user does not. Since you *do* have read access, you can bypass the issue by running `bash ./s300928290.sh`.